# Hanging a mirror on unknow wall type

Tags: walls, drywall-anchor

I need to hang a 25Kg mirror on a wall, however I do not know what type of wall it is, I think it is possibly plasterboard or thermalite blocks.

I have been looking at various fixings online, and you get a lot of variation between plasterboard and thermalite wall plugs, and also wall plugs that can be used within different wall types.

Is is best to drill the wall and find the wall type and use those specific wall plug types, or buy the wall plugs that are suitable for any wall type?

Comment: What type of mount hardware is on the mirror? How many points?

Comment: The mirror has two closed hooks on the rear, so I wanted to use two screws in the wall.

Comment: If there are any light switches/outlets on the wall, you could remove the front panel to get a good look at the wall material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of either plaster or Thermalite panels, [plastic plug-type anchors](http://www.naturalhandyman.com/iip/inffastener/infanchor/infanchor.html) should suffice. I'd use those sized for a #12 or #14 screw of adequate length (per the anchor manufacturer's suggestion), and be sure to drill exactly the correct size.

Be sure that you only leave the screw protruding only as far as necessary to allow the hooks to engage. Torsional force is what tears anchors out of walls, so you want to keep the load tight against the wall.